# React app freezes after running npm start . The issue is observed while compilation

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, create-react-app, npm-start

After running npm start my react app is either very slow in opening the page on the browser and most of the times my machine freezes and I am forced to reboot my system .
Below is my package.json file .

```
 {
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.3",
    "@material-ui/data-grid": "^4.0.0-alpha.37",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2",
    "@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.60",
    "@stripe/react-stripe-js": "^1.7.0",
    "@stripe/stripe-js": "^1.22.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "axios": "^0.24.0",
    "country-state-city": "^3.0.1",
    "overlay-navbar": "^1.1.1",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-alert": "^7.0.3",
    "react-alert-template-basic": "^1.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-helmet": "^6.1.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.2.0",
    "react-js-pagination": "^3.0.3",
    "react-material-ui-carousel": "^2.3.1",
    "react-rating-stars-component": "^2.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.6",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.0",
    "redux": "^4.1.2",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.9",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.4.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.2",
    "webfontloader": "^1.6.28"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:4000"
}
```

node version : 14.17.0
react version : 17.0.2
npm version   : 7.20.6
os: Ubuntu 20.04.3

Comment: "*my machine freezes and I am forced to reboot my system*": seems like a hardware problem. What are your machine specs?

Answer (score -1):

To solve this issue permanently you need to remove the nodejs and npm completely from your computer.
Windows Users can uninstall npm and node and can download the latest one and install. If you have any issue please follow this post to install node and npm.
Linux Users can uninstall and remove nodejs and npm by running the following command.

```js
sudo apt-get remove nodejs
sudo apt-get remove npm
```

more details are given on this link go and follow it, very helpful
https://aboutreact.com/problem-after-running-npm-start-execution-got-stucked-on-starting-running-packager/